# How to use enhanced session of Hyper-V on Ubuntu 22.04 desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp, hyper-v

I use a enchanced session of Hyper-V(RDP over VSock) by xrdp on Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop.

But Some desktop components are not working on enhanced session. I guess the compoentns require wayland not X11.

Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop recommends use gnome-remote-desktop for remote desktop, not xrdp.

Can gnome-remote-destktop support Enhanced session of Hyper-V(RDP over VSock)?
Can xrdp work with wayland?